# Itextsharp chinese character not shown in PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I need so help with my coding. I am trying to convert a HTML with Chinese Character to PDF. I manage to Convert but my chinese characters has disappear

This is my HTML file which i convert to string and i have set font with Arial Unicode MS in the td

```
string HTMLTemplate = "<table border=0 cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'><tr><td style='width:100%;font: 10px/1.5em Verdana, Arial Unicode MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>GIGI无合约 F&B‎</td></tr></table>"
```

This is my code

```
XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
fontProvider.Register("C:\\fonts\\ARIALUNI.TTF");

CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);

iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 7, 7, 7, 7);

iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create));

iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);

htmlContext.SetTagFactory(iTextSharp.tool.xml.html.Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

//create a cssresolver to apply css
iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.css.ICSSResolver cssResolver = iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);

//Create and attach pipline, without pipline parser will not work on css
iTextSharp.tool.xml.IPipeline pipeline = new iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.end.PdfWriterPipeline(doc, writer)));

//Create XMLWorker and attach a parser to it
iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorker worker = new iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser xmlParser = new iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser(worker);


//All is well open documnet and start writing.
doc.Open();

xmlParser.Parse(new StringReader(AP_TEMPLATE_HTML));
doc.NewPage();

doc.Close();
```

Comment: You are still using **iTextSharp**, which means that you are using the old version 5. Have you tried **iText for .NET**? Version 7 is a complete rewrite of the old iText, with much better support for non-Western languages. See the [HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml) and the [iText 7 download information](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET).

Comment: Hi Bruno. Yes i will love to change but is a legacy application so the mgt prefer to re look into the code then to re code at the time being.

Comment: Is that legacy application a closed source application? If so, are you complying with the rules of the AGPL, or are you a paying customer? If the latter, please contact support at iText Software (a closed ticketing system using JIRA). Stack Overflow doesn't allow its service to be used as a support platform.

Comment: Hi Bruno. Noted Thanks